# How to refresh Facebook window after user login

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

My MVC application is detect first if user is logged into Facebook:\

```
function isLoggedIn(callback, param1) {
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            updateUser(response.authResponse);
            callback(param1);
        } else {
            login(callback, param1);
        }
    });
}
```

if user not connectd i use this function to login:

```
function login(callback, success) {
    window.FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            updateUser(response.authResponse, callback, success);
            callback(success);
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

And in addition i subscribed to change status:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            top.location.href = top.location.href;
          //window.location.reload();
        }
        if (response.status != 'connected' && response.status != 'not_authorized') {
            updateUser(null);
        }
    });
```

I must refresh page after user login to get FacebookSignedRequest on server.

top.location.href = top.location.href and  window.location.reload() is not working...
any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload()` does work.

If it doesn't the code never executes or you overwrote the global `location` variable somewhere.

Comment: location.reload() work bad : in chrome is redirect page to https://apps.facebook.com/appId/ and throw Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Comment: After refreshing page (in Firefox) user still not connected